# While Signout the application in ROR, I got the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving the following error while I sign out my application. This error is only found after I add an import concept in my application.

**My routes.rb file:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :userdetails do
    collection {post :import}
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
root to: "userdetails#index"

devise_scope :users do
 get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
 get 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
end
end
```

**Controller file:**

```
class UserdetailsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :set_userdetail, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /userdetails
  # GET /userdetails.json
def import
    Userdetail.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Data imported"
  end
```

**Routes:**

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
```

**Here's my Error:**

> Unknown action Could not find devise mapping for path "/sign_out".
>   This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route
>   inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get
>   "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a
>   Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell
>   Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] =
>   Devise.mappings[:user]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace  `get 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'` with `delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :userdetails do
    collection {post :import}
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
root to: "userdetails#index"

devise_scope :users do
 get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
 delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
end
end
```

Comment: If I replace `get` with `delete`, I got a Routing error

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/sign_out"

Comment: `<a href="/sign_out" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>` http://localhost:3000/sign_out

Comment: <a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a> replace it with your link

Comment: Thank You Mr. Mayur Shah. I get resolve my error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Mayur Shah, again I got a routing error while I sign out the application. Would you please help me.  No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"

Comment: Have you changed something?

Comment: No I never change anything till yesterday It was working fine but today I start run application I show me a error.

Comment: * No I never change anything, till yesterday It was working fine but today I start run my application It show me a error.

Comment: Please check your code and restart your server as well.

Comment: You are right thanks. I just restart my server its work fine. thanks

Comment: One more help I am trying my application to automate through cucumber script. would you please help for that

Comment: I would suggest you that post another question for this issue, you will get more help.

Comment: Ya I already post my question, here is the title and link "How to fetch the file from local window by cucumber rails automation?"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897808/how-to-fetch-the-file-from-local-window-by-cucumber-rails-automation

Comment: Great!, Make sure that you have added enough description on the question so the expert can easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log out via GET method, then just replace following in your `/config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

with

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

and it should work. There is no need to manually make any changes in the generated `/sign_out` link HTML markup.

For more details I would suggest you to go through the initializer file to know about the default values used.

Also you can refer this Devise wiki page [How To: Change the default sign_in and sign_out routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) wherein there is mentioned about this config option (quoted below for quick view)

> Note that if you are making use of the :sign_out_via configuration option, then the signout action above may cause errors. You can duplicate the default behavior (which changes from delete to get based on :sign_out_via) by specifying: