# How to fetch the file from local window by cucumber rails automation?

Tags: cucumber

I use cucumber automation for my rails application. If I run the cucumber, It can't fetch the csv file from local window.
My Step-definition file:

```
When("I upload a file") do
  attach_file("#{Rails.root}/rec.csv")
  sleep(2)
  click_button 'open'
  browser.button(xpath: '/html/body/div/form/input[4]').click
  sleep(2)
end
```

Error Shown:

> Scenario: Uploading a valid csv file       # features/user.feature:23
>       Given I visit the file upload page       # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:89
>       When I upload a file                     # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:94
>         wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3) (ArgumentError)
>         ./features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:95:in `"I upload a file"'
>         features/user.feature:25:in`When I upload a file'
>       Then the number of records are displayed # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:102
>
> Failing Scenarios: cucumber features/user.feature:23 # Scenario:
>   Uploading a valid csv file
>
> 2 scenarios (1 failed, 1 passed) 6 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 4
>   passed) 0m16.032s

Comment: You can try using 
`browser.file_field(QUERY_TO_FIND_ELEMENT).set(PATH_TO_FILE)`. I wouldn't recommend using system windows in your test. You're testing your website, not the browser.

Comment: I change my code as u said, `browser.file_field(:file => 'rec.csv').set(Path:'/home/......./list')` but I got a following error,          **When I upload a file                     # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:94
      no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)
      ./features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:97:in `"I upload a file"'
      features/user.feature:25:in `When I upload a file'**

Comment: Read my comment once more, very carefully, and spot the errors

Comment: I am beginner to cucumber rails would u please help me

Comment: The error you're getting is telling you that 1 of the functions you're using (either `.file_field`, or `.set`) is expecting a string, but you're giving a hash.